# EF Code First date field to equal current time

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a field in my model class like below:

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
```

I would like that this field be set to DateTime.Now by default, unless a value was given. In MSSQL server this can be achieved in the table design view by setting the date field's  property "Default Value or Binding" to getdate() - I think, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set default values in constructor of your model class,

```
public YourModel(){
    this.DatePosted =DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: This will give he a date time with the date that the objects was created not the date that it was saved in the database

Comment: @GabrielMonteiroNepomuceno Then we can do it by overriding the SaveChanges method in the db context. In that method get the created objects and update their DatePosted.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156818/entity-framework-4-1-dbcontext-override-savechanges-to-audit-property-change

Answer (score 0):

how can we add a DB contraint do do that.

some thing that will do the below SQL

[DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT GetDate(),