# Entity Framework 6: audit/track changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, audit, audit-trail

I have my core project in C#.

I work on a database, where some tables have the columns "user_mod" and "date_mod" for sign who and when made some mods and the same with "data_new" and "user_new".

My question: is there a way to centralize this and make this data inserted automatically, where I create the instance of `dbContext`?

If not, I will use an audit trail tool. I have seen some of these, but there is a problem: all of these, require some code in my model. But I don't want to write in my model, because if I have to change it, I will lost the mods. Is it possible use an audit trail for EF6 without writing in the model file(s)? How?

EDIT:

My attempt to override the saveChanges.

```
public partial class PieEntities : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions options)
    {
        var timestamp = DateTime.Now;

        EntityState es = EntityState.Added;
        ObjectStateManager o = new ObjectStateManager();

        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in o.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added ))  {
            if (entry.Entity.GetType() == typeof(TabImpianti)) {
                TabImpianti impianto = entry.Entity as TabImpianti;
                impianto.DATA_INS = timestamp;
                impianto.DATA_MOD = timestamp;
                string u = mdlImpostazioni.p.UserName;
                impianto.USER_INS = u;
                impianto.USER_MOD = u;
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges(options);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: I've summarized the [solution here](https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2016/02/11/entity-framework-6-audittrack-changes/).**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework DbContext SaveChanges() OriginalValue Incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588352/entity-framework-dbcontext-savechanges-originalvalue-incorrect). There are many more efforts in this area. Look for Entity Framework + auditing.

Comment: @GertArnold why? I don't think so. Further, that question is about EF4, two versions older of mine.

Comment: Well, I picked a random one from a long list of hits when I search StackOverflow on this topic. It usually amounts to overriding `SaveChanges`, which is the same in EF4. In EF6 you may venture something in the area of command tree interceptors, but I'm not sure where that will take you.

Comment: @PieroAlberto your ObjectStateManager must come from the context: assign it from this `(this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectStateManager`

Comment: Regarding the base call, I don't see why it would pose a problem. I think you don't need to tell the compiler you are inheriting from a DbContext again though, remove the `: DbContext`

Comment: @samy now:  foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added )) --> it says that ObjectStateManager doens't exist.

Comment: @samy and, with and without ":dbContext", it doens't find saveChanges to override...

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If using EF6's `DbContext` you can use `ChangeTracker` in `SaveChanges` override to find added/modified entities of custom type, for example IAuditedEntity.

```
public interface IAuditedEntity {
  string CreatedBy { get; set; }
  DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
  string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
  DateTime LastModifiedAt { get; set; }
}

public override int SaveChanges() {
  var addedAuditedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditedEntity>()
    .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Added)
    .Select(p => p.Entity);

  var modifiedAuditedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditedEntity>()
    .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified)
    .Select(p => p.Entity);

  var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

  foreach (var added in addedAuditedEntities) {
    added.CreatedAt = now;
    added.LastModifiedAt = now;
  }

  foreach (var modified in modifiedAuditedEntities) {
    modified.LastModifiedAt = now;
  }

  return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: your code looks simply, but I have just tried it... I have inserted a new item in one of my tables and it didn't enter in the for of addedEntities.. how does it work? what can I do?

Comment: Entities that you want to track/audit must implement `IAuditedEntity`

Comment: my entities? but my entities are defined in the model... and I don't want to mod manually the auto-generated model. How can I do it? (excuse me the dum question)

Comment: Then use `TabImpianti` in place of `IAuditedEntity` and replace property names to match your model.

Comment: TabImpianti is only one of tables I want track. Do I create one interface for each tables?

Comment: If you want to track multiple entities then its easier to create an interface and have all entities implement it. Then you can use the code above.

Comment: But to make all entitities implement it, have I to write in the auto-generated file? or can I do it in other way?

Comment: This solution is more for code-first approach. For Database first auto-generated entities, you will probably have to check types of each entity when enumerating the change tracker. Use `ChangeTracker.Entries()` instead of `ChangeTracker.Entries<T>()`. Then you need to check the type for each entity when enumerating.

Comment: oook, but now, when I type "added.someAttr" it doesn't exist... can you update your answer with this example?

Comment: ok, I've almost got it, I hope... I have put this for the new record "if (added.GetType() == typeof(TabImpianti))" and it works. But the same for the modded records "if (modified.GetType() == typeof(TabImpianti))" doesn't work, it doens't pass the if condition. Why?

Comment: EF Database first entities are marked with the partial keyword. That makes it easy to assign attributes without interfering with generated code. Just create a new file `AuditedEntries.cs` containing `[IAuditedEntity] public partial class TabImpianti {}`

Comment: Just to be clear, since each entity implements the `IAuditedEntity` interface the properties are part of the individual entities so they are saved to the same table correct?

Answer (score 6):

There is one way to do it: you can create a partial class that is the same name as your object context and implement an override of the `SaveChanges` method. In this override you can look at all the changes that will be pushed to the DB and process them.

You can process them any way you like, in the following example I created an interface `IAutoTimestampEntity` that contained a creation date and a modification date. Any object of this type would be automatically updated with the time of change.

```
public override int SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions options)
{
    var timestamp = DateTime.Now;

    foreach (var InsertedAutoTimestampEntity in ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added).Select(ose => ose.Entity).OfType<IAutoTimestampEntity>())
    {
        InsertedAutoTimestampEntity.CreationDate = timestamp;
        InsertedAutoTimestampEntity.ModificationDate = timestamp;
    }

    foreach (var UpdatedAutoTimestampEntity in ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Modified).Select(ose => ose.Entity).OfType<IAutoTimestampEntity>())
    {
        UpdatedAutoTimestampEntity.ModificationDate = timestamp;
    }

    return base.SaveChanges(options);
}
```

You can use the same principle, or you can look at the type of each changed entity in details. I like the declarative aspect of the interface though. It lets you expose one aspect of automation explicitly instead of letting it be done silently by the EF layer.

If you have a `DbContext` instead of an `ObjectContext`, cast your `DbContext` to `IObjectContextAdapter` to access the `ObjectStateManager`

Comment: nice!! Is it also possible to see what is a delete?

what are InsertedAutoTimestampEntity and UpdatedAutoTimestampEntity?

Comment: InsertedAutoTimeStampEntity and UpdatedAutoTimestampEntity are the names I gave the entities in the enumeration, so it is just naming.

Comment: Regarding the delete, here is the EntityState enum, you can see deleted is present as well as other states you can track: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have added the reference to System.entity. But it says that "ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added)" it isn't a static method and I have to instance it. Whty in your code isn't in this way?

Comment: If you are using a `DbContext` instead of an `ObjectContext`, cast your `DbContext` to `IObjectContextAdapter` to access the `ObjectStateManager`

Comment: @PieroAlberto - there is more than one way to do auditing.  Off the top of my head, STE's, Triggers, Database level auditing (built into SQL Server), etc.. This method will get slower and slower the more objects that are added to the Local cache.  It also won't track changes made through non-EF means like in SSMS or Database.ExecuteSqlCommand calls.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch you are right, however unless you have windows auth forwarded to the DB this is the only way you can get things like the current user. I seldom see this kind of DB setup, is it really recommended?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I don't know STE's though, what is it?

Comment: self-tracking entities, though they're discouraged...  I don't understand your point about auth.. auth has nothing to do with auditing.

Comment: As samy says, I also need the user logged in.

@samy the last row, "return base.SaveChanges(options);" is red underlined... why? it says that there aren't method of saveChanges with one parameter... Now I will update the code

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch excuse me, but, how caon you track the timestamp and WHO did some action?

Comment: @PieroAlberto - just make your entities auto-populate the user via the constructor.  Not difficult.

Comment: @samy last big problem: in the definiot row, where you write "override" it says me that there arent' method to override. why?

Comment: You can write a trigger to log who made the changes if your users log in to SQL using Windows authentication. But if you have a web site where there is only one database user then you you should use the override of SaveChanges and somehow pass in the name of the current user: for example add a property CurrentUserName to your DbContext

Comment: solved with these hints and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004707/unexpected-gettype-result-for-entity-entry

Answer (score 1):

Addition to the answer from @AlaaMasoud.

With `CreatedDate` and `UpdatedDate`:

```
interface IEntityDate
{
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}

public abstract class EntityBase<T1>: IEntityDate
{
    public T1 Id { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    foreach (var changedEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        if (changedEntity.Entity is IEntityDate entity)
        {
            switch (changedEntity.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entity.CreatedDate = now;
                    entity.UpdatedDate = now;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Modified:
                    Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
                    entity.UpdatedDate = now;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

To handle `CreatedBy` and `UpdatedBy` I use a wrapper for `DbContext` like this:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public interface ICurrentUser
{
    string GetUsername();
}

public class ApplicationDbContextUserWrapper
{
    public ApplicationDbContext Context;

    public ApplicationDbContextUserWrapper(ApplicationDbContext context, ICurrentUser currentUser)
    {
        context.CurrentUser = currentUser;
        this.Context = context;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{

    public ICurrentUser CurrentUser;
    
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (var changedEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (changedEntity.Entity is IEntity entity)
            {
                switch (changedEntity.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        entity.CreatedDate = now;
                        entity.UpdatedDate = now;
                        entity.CreatedBy = CurrentUser.GetUsername();
                        entity.UpdatedBy = CurrentUser.GetUsername();
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                        Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
                        entity.UpdatedDate = now;
                        entity.UpdatedBy = CurrentUser.GetUsername();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    
    ...
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53669556/3850405