# How to to handle abstract base class in entity framework(code first)?

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am implementing an audit functionality to keep track of any changes (create, update, delete) made to any type of object. For this I need a way to declare a generic object which can point to object of any other class derived from an abstract base class.

Base class I do not want to have table for in database :

```
  public abstract class EntityBase {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ModificationDateTime { get; set; }
  }

  public class EntityBaseConfigurations<TEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase {
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder) {
      builder.Property(e => e.CreationDateTime).IsRequired().HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");
      builder.Property(e => e.ModificationDateTime).IsRequired().HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");
    }
  }
```

and a couple of models derived from base for example :

```
  [Table("Initiative")]
  public class Initiative : EntityBase {
    [Key]
    public int InitiativeId { get; set; }

    // ...

    [Required]
    public Contributor Assignee { get; set; }
  }

  public class InitiativeConfiguration : EntityBaseConfigurations<Initiative> {
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Initiative> builder) => base.Configure(builder);

    // ...
  }
```

```
  [Table("Contributor")]
  public class Contributor : EntityBase {
    [Key]
    public int ContributorId { get; set; }

    // ...
  }

  public class ContributorConfiguration : EntityBaseConfigurations<Contributor> {
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Contributor> builder) => base.Configure(builder);

    // ...
  }
```

**Now my failed attempt to create the Audit model**

```
  [Table("Audit")]
  public class Audit : EntityBase {
    [Key]
    public int AuditId { get; set; }

    public User Actor {get; set;}

    // ...

    public EntityBase Entity { get; set; } // I want to be able to point to objct of any class derived from EntityBase (ex. Initiative, Contributor)
  }

  public class AuditConfiguration : EntityBaseConfigurations<Audit> {
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Audit> builder) => base.Configure(builder);
    // ...
  }
```

When I try to create a migration for audit class, I get below error

> The derived type 'Audit' cannot have KeyAttribute on property
> 'AuditId' since primary key can only be declared on the root type.

Here is my Db Context if needed

```
  public class DbContext : IdentityDbContext<User> {
    public DbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Initiative> Initiatives { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contributor> Contributors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new InitiativeConfiguration());
      modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ContributorConfiguration());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @tzman, the error message is very clear that you cannot define `[Key]` on the derived type.

Comment: @Rena I find the error message quite misleading because, if I remove "public EntityBase Entity { get; set; }" line, everything runs just fine. Also I have keys set in other classes (Initiative and Contributor) and they are working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this `Entity` property in `Audit`, EF takes a completely different path in implementing the model.

- Without it, it maps each entity to its own independent table, each table having all columns including the ones in `EntityBase`. In fact, it completely ignores `EntityBase`. As for EF, there is no inheritance.
- If it's there, EF recognizes that `Audit` needs a foreign key to *any* type derived from `EntityBase`. In order to implement this *polymorphic association*, a base table is required that "collects" all primary key values of `EntityBase` entities. `Audit` refers to this base table's primary key.

  Also, table `EntityBase` contains all shared properties (`CreationDateTime` etc), and the separate entity table only have their own properties *and* a primary key that's also a foreign key to `EntityBase`. This is referred to as *Table per Type* (TPT) inheritance.

This TPT inheritance also requires `EntityBase` to have the primary key property, implying that the inheriting entities shouldn't.

All in all, if you remove the key properties from the inheriting entities and add

```cs
public int ID { get; set; }
```

to `EntityBase`, EF will be able to map your class model.

However, be aware of the [ins and outs of TPT inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration), esp. the warning

> In many cases, TPT shows inferior performance when compared to TPH.

And, of course, more so compared to no inheritance.

Comment: Is there any better way this audit functionality can be implemented or should I go with TPT inheritance? Basically I need a common place to manage audit information for all kind of operations.

Comment: That's a broad subject with many options. Many do it by overriding SaveChanges. [Just one example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26355486/861716). I wouldn't use TPT inheritance for it though, because it has considerable impact on the class model, only for a cross-cutting concern.

Comment: Of course I mean database model, not class model.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] attribute from  public DateTime CreationDateTime  propert of EntityBase.

Also I would remove

```
public EntityBase Entity { get; set; }
```

from Audit class , you would not be able to use it. Or you can try to make it not mapped

```
[NotMapped]
public EntityBase Entity { get; set; }
```