# Overriding the Deletion of Entities

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I need to store a file in conjunction with a database entry.  How can I override the `Remove` method of the `DbContext` so that both the entry *and* file are deleted?

Comment: Couldn't you setup a trigger to do that for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `SaveChanges` method, as described here: [Entity Framework 4.1 DbContext Override SaveChanges to Audit Property Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156818/entity-framework-4-1-dbcontext-override-savechanges-to-audit-property-change)

Just add your own case for removals of specific entity types.

Answer (score 0):

I would create new class extending of DbSet which pushes all other things through to the base but with remove it does your file change as well. This should work fine with DBcontext. It also means you can have your `FileAndDbSet<T>` used for some entities and regular `DbSet<T>` for the ones you dont have files with