# How should I go about overriding the SaveChanges() method on DbContext in order to maintain deleted/modified records using EF 4.3?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to maintain all modified records and deleted records in my project and track their status using a Status column.  Below is the code from my first attempt but it seems I cannot cast `OriginalValues.ToObject()` to DbEntityEntry for obvious reasons.  How shoudl I go about accomplishing this?

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var currentUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        var trackedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<ITrackable>();

        foreach (var trackedEntity in trackedEntities)
        {
            switch(trackedEntity.State)
            {
                case System.Data.EntityState.Added:
                    trackedEntity.Entity.CreatedDate = now;                        
                    trackedEntity.Entity.CreatedBy = currentUser;                        
                    trackedEntity.Entity.Status = Status.Active;
                    break;
                case System.Data.EntityState.Modified:                        
                    var originalEntity = trackedEntity.OriginalValues.ToObject() as DbEntityEntry<ITrackable>;                        
                    originalEntity.Entity.ModifiedDate = now;
                    originalEntity.Entity.ModifiedBy = currentUser;
                    originalEntity.Entity.Status = Status.Modified;

                    var newEntity = trackedEntity.CurrentValues.ToObject() as DbEntityEntry<ITrackable>;
                    newEntity.State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
                    newEntity.Entity.Status = Status.Active;                                                
                    break;
                case System.Data.EntityState.Deleted:
                    trackedEntity.State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                    trackedEntity.Entity.Status = Status.Deleted;
                    break;                            
            }                
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: may be this is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156818/entity-framework-4-1-dbcontext-override-savechanges-to-audit-property-change

Comment: Thank you definitely a help but I am hoping there is a way other than looping through the properties.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve in the `Modified` case. But my understanding is that `ToObject()` creates a completely new object and fills it with the property values from the `OriginalValues` dictionary. So, `originalEntity` is not attached to the context and will just be garbage collected without any effect when the variable goes out of scope.

Therefore, don't you need to save the `originalEntity` as a new added entity to the database to save the last version before the modification is saved?

I would try this:

```
case System.Data.EntityState.Modified:                        
    var originalEntity = trackedEntity.OriginalValues.ToObject() as ITrackable;
    originalEntity.ModifiedDate = now;
    originalEntity.ModifiedBy = currentUser;
    originalEntity.Status = Status.Modified;
    Entry(originalEntity).Status = System.Data.EntityState.Added;

    trackedEntity.Entity.Status = Status.Active;
    break;
```

`trackedEntity` will be saved anyway because it is in state `Modified` and `originalEntity` would be created and saved as a new object which represents the state before modification.

I expect that the cast to `ITrackable` should work because `ToObject()` creates an object of the type which is represented by the `OriginalValues` dictionary, and that must be an `ITrackable` because you filter the `ChangeTracker.Entries` enumeration by this interface.

The above is untested, I am unsure if it will work.

**Edit**

The naming above is a bit confusing because `originalEntity` is an entity in your model while `trackedEntity` is a `DbEntityEntry<T>`. Maybe rename that either to `originalEntityObject` (ugly) or better `trackedEntityEntry`.

Just to mention: It's absolutely necessary (unless you are using change tracking proxies consequently) that you call `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` before you enter the `foreach` loop because otherwise the entries are possibly not in the correct final state and you enter wrong `case` sections or no section at all (when the state is `Unchanged` but still has changed properties). POCO changes are detected by comparison with the snapshot in `OriginalValues` and this last comparison is done in `base.SaveChanges` which is *after* your loop and too late. (See also "Edit 2" in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6157071/270591.)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for how you should override SaveChanges() to implement a similar goal

it would be easier to cast like this;

```
((ITrackable)trackedEntity.Entity).CreatedDate = now;
```

Answer (score 0):

Though not identical to the methodology you're using, I use the repository pattern for this.  The rest of the app just instantiates the repository class, and calls `Save(objToSave)` or `Delete(objToDelete)` or similar.  Now the execution process is disconnected from the actual data store, and I can take appropriate action: update the `ModifyDate`, change the `Status`, etc.  If you're exposing the `DataContext` to the rest of the application, it's very hard to control the details under the hood.