# Logging history of user changes in EF CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework, logging, ef-code-first

I want save history of user changes on DB Records. Changes such as edit records (for example value of FirstName field changed from 'n ' to 'x' by user1 in yyyy/dd/mm") , Delete Records and ... .


please suggest a method to implement this in EF codefirst.

**After Edit:**
And which one is better? 
1.Create one table to save all tables log 
2.Create a table for each table in database

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6156818/270591

Comment: Of Course.But i edit question.please check it...

Comment: From what you describe I see only that you need a log table with something like this: Date, User, TableName, RecordIdentifier (PK value probably), ColumnName, OldValue, NewValue, Action (Delete, Insert, Update?). Do you see any benefit in option 2?

Comment: it is great...
Please answer below and i choose it as correct answer.tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the SaveChanges method.

In your SaveChanges method loop through the entries using ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries

Then use the ObjectStateEntry CurrentValues.DataRecordInfo.FieldMetadata[].FieldType.Name and the entry.CurrentValues  to get the name value pairs